# csv carriage return don't show up in Excel

Tags: excel, csv, carriage-return

I want to import a csv file in Excel. The csv file has carriage returns but Excel don't show them (see picture 1). The carriage return only comes up when i select the text in the cell and press enter.

Is there a way to solve this automatically? (vba)

- I've tried to substitute the carriage return by a semicolon, but Excel does not find the carriage return. (=SUBSTITUTE(F2, CHAR(10), ";")
- Text wrap is turned on in the cells
- I tried to find the carriage return with a macro and the "instr()" function but Excel does not find the Chr(10).

```css
Sub FindCarriageReturn()

myPos = InStr(1, Range("F2"), Chr(10))

End Sub
```

All documents: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Kwr1VjCSdxtbtNcM6h5Rl8tc_Mo9XIA6

Thanks in advance!

Dieter

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nBI3.png)

Comment: Do you have text wrapping turned on for those cells?

Comment: if i turn it on, there is no difference

Comment: Can you upload a text (csv) file that demonstrates the problem (with sensitive information removed)?  Upload to some sharing site (eg DropBox, OneDrive, etc) and post a link in your question.

Comment: It is done. The link will give you the csv file, the excel-file with the problem and the excel-file with the desired result. If there is any problem with the link, please tell me. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Your CSV file contains a carriage return (**CR**, CHAR(13), `Chr(13)` or `vbCr` in VBA) within the data, and carriage return & line feed (**CR LF**, CHAR(10) & CHAR (13), `vbCrLf` in VBA) at the end of each line.

If you open the CSV file with e. g. [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org), it looks like this:

[image: CSV file with notepad++]

As Excel needs a line feed within a cell to get visible text wrapping, you may use a formula like this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(F2, CHAR(13), CHAR(10))
```